# The triangle ABC and AD is the bisector of the angle BAC. We know that the area of ABC = 3*area of ABD How many natural values can the BC take?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, bisection

The triangle ABC has the length of the side AB equal to an integer greater than or equal to 1, and AD is the bisector of the angle BAC, D belonging to BC. It is known that the area of ABC = 3* the area of ABD. How many natural values can the length of side BC take?

**MY IDEAS**

*MY DRAWING*

[image]

Okey, so I thought of writing the both area as:

$A(ABC)=\frac {h\cdot BC}{2}=3\cdot A(ABD)= \frac{h\cdot BD}{2}$

where h= the height of BC.

$\frac {h\cdot BC}{2}=\frac{h\cdot BD}{2}$ we can multiply it by 2 and eliminate the height

$BC=3BD$

so, $DC=2BD$, then $\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{1}{2}$

we can apply the theorm of the bisector and

$\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{AB}{AC}$

After this we can write AB as a and AC as 2a

I don't know what to do along! Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the triangle inequality?

Comment: @UmeshShankar Oooo....Yes, I know about it.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think so. It's from a math book so I guess it should have a response. There aren't any missing conditions, sadly....

Comment: Ah, I missed the condition that $a$ was an integer. In which case you are already there with the triangle inequality: $2a-a=a<BC<3a=2a+a$ so the length of $BC$ must be one of $2a-1$ possible values: $a+1, a+2,\ldots,3a-1$.

Comment: But why should BC be bigger than a???

Comment: Triangle inequality again: $AB+BC>AC$ i.e. $a+BC>2a$ i.e. $BC>a$.

Comment: Ooooo....thank you from the bottom of my heart!!!!!!!!